# gitlab docker nginx reverse proxy to a sub path

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I'm trying to setup nginx as a reverse proxy to route `apps.mycompany.com/gitlab` to a gitlab docker container running on the same server as nginx:

nginx config has:

```
location /gitlab/ {
    proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```

the first http call `apps.mycompany.com/gitlab` goes smoothly but basically all the hrefs inside the html (e.g. `href:"/assets/..."`) are still routing to `apps.mycompany.com/assets/...` instead of `apps.mycompany.com/gitlab/assets/...`

So no assets and css files are found. The rendered page has structure but no styling and I don't even know what else doesn't work.

I don't know nginx enough to know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you check if the request for your assets are getting a `redirect` response?  Did you check [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: No. They're all getting 404 not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NGINX**

In your nginx configuration add `proxy_set_header` option and change `proxy_pass` like following:

```
location /gitlab/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/gitlab/;
}
```

**GITLAB**

What you are looking for is **relative URL** configuration in GitLab.

If you have GitLab in version **8.5** or above do one of following depending on your GitLab deployment type:

**DOCKER-COMPOSE deployment**

Add environment variable `external_url` to your `docker-compose.yml` file, sample file:

```
gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.5.2-ce.0'
    restart: always
    environment:
            GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
                    external_url 'http://apps.mycompany.com/gitlab/'
    ports:
            - '3000:80'
```

Then restart GitLab docker:

`docker-compose up -d`

**DOCKER deployment**

If you are not using docker-compose (which I **strongly** recommend) then you can add `external_url` option to you `docker run` command, sample execution:

`docker run --detach --publish 3000:80 --restart always --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://apps.mycompany.com/gitlab/'" gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.5.2-ce.0`

**GitLab configuration files update - can be used in all kinds of deployments**

Another approach is to directly modify the GitLab configuration file but I would recommend that for standalone GitLab installations not for docker deployments.

Modify GitLab configuration in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` change the `external_url` value to following:

`external_url "http://apps.mycompany.com/gitlab"`

Afther this change you have to reconfigure GitLab:

`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Then restart service:

`sudo gitlab-ctl restart`

You can find more details about GitLab configuration in [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#enable-relative-url-in-gitlab).

I recommend that you also check GitLab in docker deployment [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/).

Please note that relative URL support in Omnibus GitLab is **experimental** and was introduced in version 8.5 (for earlier version you need to compile it from source - [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/relative_url.html)).

Answer (score 1):

My gitlab setting for https:

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.yourdomain.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.yourdomain.com'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 9122
      nginx['enable'] = true
      nginx['listen_port'] = 9180
      nginx['listen_https'] = false
  ports:
    - '9180:9180'
    - '9122:22'
  volumes:
    - '/opt/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/opt/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

nginx gitlab.conf:

```
server {
  listen       443;
  server_name  gitlab.yourdomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9180;
  }
}
```